# Making my own Carbon Footprint Calculator

Tags: equation, calculator

I'm trying create my own carbon footprint calculator, but I'm having trouble finding all the proper equations and such online, anyone know of any decent resources?

Comment: Send me an email if you would like to talk about working on such a web based project together. firstname.lastname@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that is a huge question.  In part because "all the proper equations" really depend on who is doing the asking.  I would start here: http://www.withouthotair.com/

This resource is HUGE for this. =)

Comment: Don't miss the link on that page to freely download the whole book as a PDF!

Comment: Thanks for the link, I admit that they are very useful resources  +1

Answer (score 1):

I think this project sounds very interesting!

If you are familiar with web development, it would be very cool to make this a web-based project, which allows for constant growth and development of the equations. You could even make it so that users of your web site can view the equations you are using, and input their own equations. Maybe you could even consider some sort of mechanism to fold back user equations into the base - or set up multiple different bases for different users of different lifestyles.

I didn't directly answer your question, but I hope these concepts are interesting and useful to you.

-Brian J. Stinar-